# Validation of viewstate in a page returned with php and curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, viewstate, simple-html-dom

I'm quite new in PHP but for practise I wanted to write a script using curl for logging and send post request to a page site written in asp. I've used libcurl and simple_html_dom.php libraries.

Sometimes I got an error for invalid viewstate, this is the stack trace:

```
    [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 111.11.11.111
    Port: 4743
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
    ViewState: 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...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +153
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +237
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +207
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +199
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.web_articolo_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

    include('simple_html_dom.php');   

    //method for logging
    function login($url,$data){        
        $headers = array(
                'Host' => 'site',                
                'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language' => 'en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',                
                'Referer' => 'http://somesite.com',                
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            );

        $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0');
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        //$verbose = curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $ris = curl_exec ($login);
        curl_close($login);
        unset($login);
        return $ris;
    }
    //method for posting data
    function post_data($site,$data){
        $datapost = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0');
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
        $result = curl_exec ($datapost);
        curl_close ($datapost);        
        return $result;
    }

    function getParamLogin($url,$pageType) {
        //return the html page
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        $eventtarget = '';
        $eventargument = '';
        if(sizeof($html->find('[id=__EVENTTARGET]')) > 0)
            $eventtarget = $html->find('[id=__EVENTTARGET]')[0]->value;
        if(sizeof($html->find('[id=__EVENTARGUMENT]')) > 0)
            $eventargument = $html->find('[id=__EVENTARGUMENT]')[0]->value;

        //post params
        $params = array('ctl00_ScriptManager1_HiddenField' => $html->find('[id=ctl00_ScriptManager1_HiddenField]')[0]->value,
                        '__EVENTTARGET' => $eventtarget,
                        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => $eventargument,
                        '__VIEWSTATE' => $html->find('[id=__VIEWSTATE]')[0]->value,
                        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $html->find('[id=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]')[0]->value,
                        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $html->find('[id=__EVENTVALIDATION]')[0]->value,
                        'ctl00$search' => '',                        
                        'ctl00$newsletter' => ''
                );

        switch ($pageType) {                
            case 'firstpage':
                $login = array('ctl00$pagina$tlogin_area' => 'user',
                    'ctl00$pagina$tpassword_area' => 'passwd',
                    'ctl00$pagina$tinvia' => 'ACCEDI',);
                $params = array_merge($params,$login);
                break;
            case 'secondpage':
                $cart = array('__SCROLLPOSITIONX' => '0',
                    '__SCROLLPOSITIONY' => '0',
                    'ctl00$pagina$taglie' => '6M',
                    'ctl00$pagina$tag' => 'Aggiungi al carrello');
                $params = array_merge($params,$cart);
                break;            
        }
        print_r($params);
        return $params;
    }    
?>

<?php
    login('http://www.loginpage.com',  getParamLogin('http://www.loginpage.com','firstpage'));
    post_data('http://www.anotherpage.com',getParamLogin('http://www.anotherpage.com','secondpage'));
?>
```

I wonder if there is also a cookie in handle the cookie and then in the viewstate... Someone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a doPostBack on the login button? You're going to need to post the url if you want help with this.

Comment: This is the [link](http://shop.urbanjunglestore.it/web/). Thank you for the reply!

Comment: There is a doPostBack on the original page... How can I simulate it?